Unidentified smell from vents in brand new construction condo unit
I just moved into a brand new build condo and there is a smell coming from my vents. I have had HVAC guys, construction techs and roofers to look at it and nobody can figure out what the smell is. They say it is coming from the roof joists as I am on the top floor. There is a draft in my utility closet around one of the pipes. The smell is the worst when my deck door and windows are open as air is being drawn from this roof cavity. The smell is hard to describe, almost chemically like wet paint but also similar to dirty socks. Any ideas on what this smell could be? No other surrounding units have this smell. It started when the weather got warm and is the worst when it's hot and humid outside. When the AC is on it is less vs. when the windows are open.
Any ideas would be appreciated as these workers don't have any idea what they're looking for.

Animal or mold in the duct?

We have no real idea of the materials that were used in the construction,so pinning this down can be difficult. Silicone can smell like vinegar, and some paint can smell like onions, but that is opinion.
The smell may be from material/s off-gassing. This especially since you indicated the smell came about when the weather was hot. It can be temporary.
I would definitely seal around the pipe in the utility closet, and anywhere else that is not sealed.
Make the management company aware of the issue with an email, so you have proof of notification. Request that the issue be corrected within a reasonable time frame.  Be firm, but nice. This is a new building and often materials need to dry or cure.

Fiberglas insulation has its own particular aroma.

Thanks for the reply. It has been over 50 days since I reported and 8 visits later. No other units on this level have the smell so there's only an issue in my corner of the roof which makes me think it is something abnormal and not just materials gassing off as if this were the case all the upper levels would smell it. I am desperate to find an answer.

Call your local health department.  Have them check to see if there may be a health hazard.
